# Send CSV from raspberry pi3 to raspberry pi 3 with python

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, communication

This problem is making me crazy! I need to send a CSV file from one raspberry pi to another raspberry pi via bluetooth,

The CSV file will be about max 4MB, I have no problem with changing the language if anyone have a better solution.

By the way, I can't read the csv and send it line by line, I don't need that, I need to send just one file, like a compress file, to process it in the other raspberry.

Thank you very much! I will appreciate any help!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Object Exchange. Take a look at the following for more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114187/121848

Answer (score 0):

Could you use SCP to copy it over on the command line?

Comment: Thank you but I need over BT, I've consider that but is not an option